# not showing camera Preview on android

Tags: android

I want before capture, showing camera preview.
but not showing camera preview.

it is not occur error
thanks,

```
private boolean playing = false;   //global variable
private Camera mCamera;   //global variable

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
cameraPlayStart();
}



@Override
public void cameraPlayStart() {
if (!playing) {
    mCamera.startPreview();
    playing = true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (camera != null){
      try {
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
       camera.startPreview();
       previewing = true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

set prieview display of your surfaceview 
Hope this will help you ! Cheers !

Comment: I am giving you link which will give you better understand of camera previewing and its declaration .

Comment: here is link :  https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example/blob/master/src/com/example/cam/Preview.java

Comment: here is tutorial link :